# Intellij jupyter error: no module named jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook

I just upgraded to Idea 2023.3.4, installed the python and jupyter plugins, then created a new project in a python 3.12 virtual environment. Executing the first cell in a notebook yielded the error "no module named jupyter". What else is needed to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the jupyter package in the virtual environment solved this for me. In Intellij, go to `File | Project Structure... | SDKs` then select the project's virtual environment. In the right pane click on the `Packages` tab, click the `+`, type "jupyter" in the search box, select the jupyter package, and click `Install Package`.